# How do you use maps created by the edn reader in clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, edn

This prints `:bar` in *Clojure* as I would expect:

```
(println (:foo (clojure.tools.reader.edn/read-string "{:foo :bar}")))
;=> :bar
```

But this prints `nil` in *ClojureScript*:

```
(println (:foo (cljs.reader/read-string "{:foo :bar}")))
;=> nil
```

To make things stranger, this prints `:bar` in *ClojureScript* as I would expect:

```
(let [data (cljs.reader/read-string "{:foo :bar}")]
  (println ((first (keys data)) data )))
;=> :bar
```

How do I access a value in a map that was created by the reader? Is this a character encoding thing?

**Edit**

Here's the namespace as requested in the comments:

```
(ns clojuresite.homepage
  (:require-macros [hiccups.core :as hiccups])
  (:require [hiccups.runtime :as hiccupsrt]
            [cljs.nodejs :as node]
            [cljs.reader :as reader]))
```

Comment: When running the second example in a fresh clojurescript repl, I get the correct answer. What clojurescript version are you using?

Comment: The second example works for me as well, could you include the ns form for context?

Comment: Well that's really surprising to me. My cljs version is 0.0-1896. How did you get it to work in the repl? Every time I tried `(require '[cljs.reader :as reader])` I got a compile error.

Comment: I used the namespace form to require it in the repl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(.log js/console
  ((keyword "foo") (cljs.reader/read-string "{:foo :bar}")))
```

If that works, and generates `﷐:bar`, you have old generated code hanging around and you should run a `lein cljsbuild clean`.

There was a change in `0.0-1877` that switched keywords, in the generated javascript, from `﷐:foo` to `cljs.core.Keyword`.

Answer (score 2):

the **return value of println is nil** and perhaps the output from the print is likely going into another buffer if your are using emacs or being logged somewhere else. Perhaps you are seeing the return value of `println` instead of it's output.

```
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (ns cljs.user (:require [cljs.reader :as edn]))
nil
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (println (:foo (cljs.reader/read-string "{:foo :bar}")))
:bar
nil
```

vs:

```
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (:foo (cljs.reader/read-string "{:foo :bar}"))
:bar
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is what he is talking about. Note the result of the third example.

Comment: I'm not sure either, it's just a guess and an accompanying working example.